# Is there a one-tailed test for difference in data variance in a mixed model?

Tags: mixed-model, variance, categorical-data

I would like to test if the variation of my response variable is higher for one level of an explanatory variable than for the other. However I am not interested in the total variation, but only variation towards higher values of the response variable. 
My model (using the package `nlme` in R):

`lme(y~factor + covariate, random=~1|Site)`

I should specify that I do not want to look at differences in the residual variance but in the variation of the observed values.